# How to use a script to update an array of json objects in Elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to have an array of objects in my ES document. part of the document mapping is

```
mapping_data = {
        "mappings": {
            config.ES_PAIRS: {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {"type": "string"},
                    "decisions": {
                        "properties": {
                            "user": {"type": "string"},
                            "decision": {"type": "string"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

The decisions object should be an array to store different decisions consisting of the decision and the user who made the decision.
I want to be able to update the document using a script.

```
body = {
        "script": "ctx._source.decisions.user += user; ctx._source.decisions.decision += decision",
        "params": {
            "decision": user,
            "user": user
        }
    }
    es.update(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type=DOC_TYPE, id=ID, body=body)
```

Im using the python client.
I get the a failed to execute script error. Please help.

```
File "/Users/..ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 83, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'RemoteTransportException[[Hannibal King][inet[/10.7.103.39:9300]][update]]; nested: ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: PropertyAccessException[[Error: could not access: user; in class: java.util.ArrayList]\n[Near : {... ctx._source.decisions.user+use ....}]\n             ^\n[Line: 1, Column: 1]]; ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to user and decision object if exist then update.

```
body = {
    "script": "if (ctx._source.decisions['user'] != null && ctx._source.decisions['decision'] != null) {ctx._source.decisions.user += user; ctx._source.decisions.decision += decision }",
    "params": {
        "decision": user,
        "user": user
    }
}
es.update(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type=DOC_TYPE, id=ID, body=body)
```